# What was the wealth distribution in US antebellum North / South

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, economy, slavery

My question relates to the following quote from chapter XI of the [Narrative of the Life of Frederick Douglass](https://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Douglass/Narrative/Douglass_Narrative.pdf):

> I  had  very  strangely supposed, while in slavery, that few of the comforts, and scarcely  any  of  the  luxuries,  of  life  were  enjoyed  at  the  north, compared  with  what  were  enjoyed  by  the  slaveholders  of  the south.  I  probably  came  to  this  conclusion  from  the  fact  that northern  people  owned  no  slaves.  I  supposed  that  they  were about upon a level with  the non-slaveholding population of the south.  I  knew  they  were  exceedingly  poor,  and  I  had  been accustomed to regard their poverty as the necessary consequence  of  their  being  non-slaveholders.  I  had  somehow
> imbibed  the  opinion  that,  in  the  absence  of  slaves,  there  could
> be  no  wealth,  and  very  little  refinement.  And  upon  coming  to
> the  north,  I  expected  to  meet  with  a  rough,  hard-handed,  and
> uncultivated population, living in the most Spartan-like simplicity,  knowing  nothing  of  the  ease,  luxury,  pomp,  and grandeur  of  southern  slaveholders.  Such  being  my  conjectures, any  one  acquainted  with  the  appearance  of  New  Bedford  may
> very readily infer how palpably I must have seen my mistake...
> Here I found
> myself surrounded with the strongest proofs of wealth... From the wharves I strolled around and over the town,
> gazing  with  wonder  and  admiration  at  the  splendid  churches,
> beautiful  dwellings,  and  finely-cultivated  gardens;  evincing  an
> amount of wealth, comfort, taste, and refinement, such as I had
> never seen in any part of slaveholding Maryland.
> ...But  the  most  astonishing  as  well  as  the  most
> interesting thing to me was the condition of the colored people,
> a  great  many  of  whom,  like  myself,  had  escaped  thither  as  a
> refuge  from  the  hunters  of  men.  I  found  many,  who  had  not
> been seven  years out of their chains, living in finer houses, and
> evidently enjoying more of the comforts of life, than the
> average  of  slaveholders  in  Maryland.  I  will  venture  to  assert,
> that  my  friend  Mr.  Nathan  Johnson... lived  in  a  neater  house;  dined  at  a  better  table;  took,  paid
> for,  and  read,  more  newspapers;  better  understood  the  moral,
> religious, and political character of the nation,—than nine tenths
> of the slaveholders in Talbot county Maryland. Yet Mr. Johnson
> was  a  working  man.  His  hands  were  hardened  by  toil,  and  not
> his  alone,  but  those  also  of  Mrs.  Johnson.

**Are there other historical data that back up or contradict Douglass's observations?** For example, did tradesmen in the urban northeast commonly live in greater material comfort than slaveholding plantation owners in the south? Are there records about wealth distribution and stratification in slaveholding vs free states at this time?

Comment: prima facia, I am skeptical.  the constant complaint of the South was against the "money men" of the North.    Of course a comparison will be difficult - do you compare the median income of each? or the income of the top quintile of each? We certainly don't want to compare plantation owners (the 1%) to tradesmen (analogous to middle class).

Comment: "New England was the poorest region, and the South was the richest" _[NBER.org](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w19861/w19861.pdf)_

Comment: @MCW - Correct me if I'm wrong...I just skimmed, but it looks like that paper is using average ("per capita") income. Averages give really distorted results in the event of large disparities. The per-capita wealth of you and Bill Gates is in the billions. This kind of effect is why I'm not real sure how I would approach answering this question. Its quite possible the *median* free man in NE was better off. More likely they were quite similar.

Comment: I also just skimmed. On the one hand, I agree with your skepticism. On the other hand, I'm reluctant to go toe to toe with NBER.  I think that OP might want to refine the question so that we could find an answer that more precisely fits the question.

Comment: @MCW that was an interesting read but they were only looking through 1774, which predates the invention of the cotton gin and early industrialization in the north.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some rough economic facts for a start. The North had four times the GDP of the South. The North had 22 million people. The South had 9.5 million people, of which just under 4.0 million were slaves, so 5.5 million white people. If you divide the *white* populations, you get a four to one North/South ratio, the same as the GDP ratio. This means that the northern and southern per capital GDPs were equivalent, **but only if you count the nearly 4.0 million black slaves as property, and their production as part of *white* per capita GDP.** If you divide the South's GDP by all 9.5 million people, including blacks, the southern standard of living was on average, 61% of the northern.

It follows therefore, that the average white southerner who didn't own any slaves was much worse off than the average white northerner (who also didn't own any slaves). The second thing is the "nine tenths of the slaveholders" who had ONE slave were barely better off than the poor white farmers that had none.

The last question is how much Mr. Nathan Johnson's (northern) standard of living was below that of the average white northerner. Presumably, there was some "discount," but probably not all the way down to "61%." It made sense that he was better off than southern whites who owned 0 or even one slave. It was the large plantation owners with tens or hundreds of slaves that were wealthy. The South was a very unequal society, with 1%-2% of the people at the very top, and the rest below that of the northern "average."

Source: Gary Becker, "The Economics of Discrimination"